# Performing PCR on samples whose DNA concentration is nul

Tags: pcr, dna-replication

Is it vain to perform a PCR on samples whose DNA concentration was measured as nul by a NanoDrop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you could get amplification from samples that are orders of magnitude below the nanodrop detection limit (~2 ng/uL). To compare: most manuals for polymerases recommend 1 ng of plasmid template, and will probably work with much less, especially if you use a few more cycles.

But if you expected to see something on the nanodrop, and you get nothing, something else might be completely wrong.

Comment: You can go down into the picogram range. And you could use nested PCR to ensure specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Some times nanodrop is unreliable. However, to be sure that you are not wasting your time, I would redo the extraction. Nanodrop in a lot of PCR methods is a control test to validate that the extraction went well. So, I would redo the extraction if I where you.